# I don't understand how to use toupper and isalpha with .txt file string input

Tags: c++

My program is largely incomplete, but I assumed that using toupper to modify the strings following their input from the textfile would work to change all the characters of said string to uppercase. I read that  works with type int, or what I assume is Ascii in this case. But I'm not really sure where to go from here. What is the most efficient means of converting and checking strings from a textfile as far as beginner C++ goes?

I've googled this issue and found a wide variety of ways, such as using std::transform, but I feel like my instructor would only want us using methods taught from our book 'Starting out with C++' by Tony Gaddis. Unfortunately I'm not finding any reference in my book where toupper is being used on textfile input, only on char values. For education's sake I'm hoping you have an idea of what I should be using here and why. I welcome recommended reading.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;
    ifstream textFile;
    int ch;
    textFile.open("letter_count.txt", ios::in);
    toupper(textFile.get());
    isalpha(textFile.get());

    if (textFile)
    {
        // Read an item from the file.
        getline(textFile, text);

        // While the last read operation
        // was successful, continue.
        while (textFile)
        {
            if (textFile)
            // Display the last item read.
            cout << text << endl;

            // Read the next item.
            getline(textFile, text);
        }

        // Close the file.
        textFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file. \n";
    }
    cout << "The most common letter is " " with " " occurances. \n";
    cout << "The least common letter is " " with " " occurances. \n";


    system("pause");
}
```

I'm getting no results from using toupper.

Comment: `std::transform(std::begin(str), std::end(str), std::begin(str), ::toupper);` is the idiomatic way of doing this in C++. If your instructor expects anything else, question it. Of course, it does help to understand what `std::transform` does: it basically just runs a loop internally on the specified range. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for a detailed description.

Comment: Have you looked up how to use `toupper()` in a reference manual like this one? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper

Comment: Separately, you can use `if (ifstream textFile{"letter_count.txt"}) { while (getline(textFile, text)) { ...do something with text... } }` - no need for `.open`, `.close` (that's done automatically in the `ifstream` destructor), and you don't need two `getline` calls or a `while (textFile)` followed by `if (textFile)` (the `if` can never fail as the `while` loop wouldn't have been entered if `textFile` wasn't good).

Comment: Thanks Tony, that was actually used as an example in my book. I wonder why they did it this way when it's inefficient?

Answer (score 2):

That is because toupper takes only one int value. Notice here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/?kw=toupper

You have to loop over  every char in your string in order  to convert it.